# C++ programming issues evaluating expressions

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that repeatedly prompts the user for 3 coefficients values a,b, and c and then will evaluate using the following expression and display the two possible values for x.
x=2c±√2a-35/b-5c

If user enters -999 for a the program should terminate. Also the screen must be cleared at the beginning and prompt the user on separate lines for b and c if -999 is not entered for a.

Also an error message must be displayed if input is invalid like division by zero or a negative sqrt. Here is what I have so far I have changed it million times in order to get it to compile and keep getting errors.

```
#include <iostream.h>                                                       
#include <cmath>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
clrscr();

float  a, b, c, x1, x2, discriminant, divisor;

//Getting values for a,b,c
cout<<"Enter the value for A (-999 to quit):  "<<endl;
cin >> a;

if(a ==-999)return 0;

cout<<"Enter the value for B: "<<endl;
cin>>b;

cout<<"Enter the value for C: "<<endl;
cin>>c;

// Evaluating
discriminant=(2*a-35);
divisor=(b-5*c)
if (discriminant >0);
{
    x1=(2*c+sqrt(discriminant))/(divisor);
    x2=(2*c-sqrt(discriminant))/(divisor);
}
else (discriminant ==0)
{
    x1=x2=(2*c)/(divisor);
}
else if (sqrt(discriminant <= -1);
cout<<"Invalid Value"<<endl;
{
else if (divisor ==0)
cout<<"Invalid Value"<<endl;
}
else
{
cout<<"x1= "<<"("<<(2*c)<<"+ i"<<sqrt(discriminant)<<")/"<<divisor<<endl;
cout<<"x2= "<<"("<<(2*c)<<"+ i"<<sqrt(discriminant)<<")/"<<divisor<<endl;
}
        system ("pause");

        return 0;
}
```

This is all screwed up from changing it so many times and I apologize for this just kinda new to this stuff.

Comment: So it doesn't work as intended, but what does it do instead ? Does it fail compile ? Does it crash ? Does it return erroneous values ?

Comment: And the problem is.....?

Comment: this line looks pretty broken, just saying... `else if (sqrt(discriminant <= -1);` you probably want a `)` instead of `;` there

Comment: The problem is it will not compile no matter how I change it. I'm getting errors on lines 28,33,34,40,43, and 51. Using borland to compile if that makes a difference (because I have to)

Comment: Strive for structure and clarity. Add code in small pieces. And then, actually *read* error messages. While they are sometimes cryptic, they usually tell what's wrong. Also, have a look at http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/O6uA6p1HH9FoK23w

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles, but the result seems incorrect.

```
//#include <iostream.h>                                                       
#include <iostream> // delete .h
#include <cmath>
//#include <conio.h> // Wandbox gcc 4.8.2 doesn't seem supporting this

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
//clrscr(); // Wandbox gcc 4.8.2 doesn't seem supporting this

float  a, b, c, x1, x2, discriminant, divisor;

//Getting values for a,b,c
cout<<"Enter the value for A (-999 to quit):  "<<endl;
cin >> a;

if(a ==-999)return 0;

cout<<"Enter the value for B: "<<endl;
cin>>b;

cout<<"Enter the value for C: "<<endl;
cin>>c;

// Evaluating
discriminant=(2*a-35);
//divisor=(b-5*c)
divisor=(b-5*c); // add semicolon here
//if (discriminant >0);
if (discriminant >0) // delete semicolon here
{
    x1=(2*c+sqrt(discriminant))/(divisor);
    x2=(2*c-sqrt(discriminant))/(divisor);
}
//else (discriminant ==0)
else if (discriminant ==0) // add if
{
    x1=x2=(2*c)/(divisor);
}
//else if (sqrt(discriminant <= -1);
else if (discriminant <= -1) // delete sqrt( and semicolon
cout<<"Invalid Value"<<endl;
//{ // delete this
else if (divisor ==0)
{ // add this
cout<<"Invalid Value"<<endl;
}
else
{
cout<<"x1= "<<"("<<(2*c)<<"+ i"<<sqrt(discriminant)<<")/"<<divisor<<endl;
cout<<"x2= "<<"("<<(2*c)<<"+ i"<<sqrt(discriminant)<<")/"<<divisor<<endl;
}
        //system ("pause"); // include cstdlib or delete this

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and I'm still getting errors
38: Code has no effect in function main()
41: Misplaced else in function main ()
43: x2 and x1 assigned a value that is never used in function main()
44:Declaration terminated incorreclty
51: declaration terminated incorrectly
52: Unexpected }

Comment: This code [do compile](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ZaQ8gj9472CNQ2sr) with one warning. Please check your code again.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>                                                       
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
//clrscr();
char exit_char;
//Why not use double
double  a, b, c, x1, x2, discriminant, divisor;
//float  a, b, c, x1, x2, discriminant, divisor;

//Getting values for a,b,c
cout<<"Enter the value for A (-999 to quit):  "<<endl;
cin >> a;

if(a ==-999)
    return 0;

cout<<"Enter the value for B: "<<endl;
cin>>b;

cout<<"Enter the value for C: "<<endl;
cin>>c;

// Evaluating
discriminant=(2*a-35);
divisor=(b-5*c); //Do you want b-(5*c) or (b-5)*c
/*if (discriminant >0);
{
    x1=(2*c+sqrt(discriminant))/(divisor);
    x2=(2*c-sqrt(discriminant))/(divisor);
}
//This is supposed to be an else if block
//else (discriminant ==0)
else 
    if(discriminant == 0)
{
    x1=x2=(2*c)/(divisor);
}
else if (sqrt(discriminant <= -1);
cout<<"Invalid Value"<<endl;
{ */
//
if(discriminant > 0)
{
    x1=(2*c+sqrt(discriminant))/(divisor);
    x2=(2*c-sqrt(discriminant))/(divisor);
}
else
{
    if(discriminant  == 0)
    {
        x1=x2=(2*c)/(divisor);
    }
    else
    {
        if(sqrt(discriminant) <= -1);
            cout<<"Invalid Value"<<endl;
    }
}

//
if (divisor == 0)
    cout<<"Invalid Value"<<endl;

else
{

    //cout<<"x1= "<<"("<<(2*c)<<"+ i"<<sqrt(discriminant)<<")/"<<divisor<<endl;
    //cout<<"x2= "<<"("<<(2*c)<<"+ i"<<sqrt(discriminant)<<")/"<<divisor<<endl;
    cout<<"x1 = "<<x1<<endl;
    cout<<"x2 = "<<x2<<endl; 
}
        //system ("pause");
    cout<<"Enter any char to quit the program"<<endl;
    cin>>exit_char;

    return 0;
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: I got the above code to work but I am not particularly sure about the program logic. I don't know exactly what you intended to do at several points within the program. It also seems that you are not certain where a semi-colon is needed.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main (void)
{
    clrscr();

    float  a, b, c, x1, x2, discriminant, divisor;

    //Getting values for a,b,c
    cout<<"Enter the value for A (-999 to quit):  "<<endl;
    cin >> a;

    if(a ==-999)return 0;

    cout<<"Enter the value for B: "<<endl;
    cin>>b;

    cout<<"Enter the value for C: "<<endl;
    cin>>c;

    // Evaluating
    discriminant=(2*a-35);
    divisor=(b-5*c)
    if (divisor ==0)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid Value"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (discriminant >0);
    {
        x1=(2*c+sqrt(discriminant))/(divisor);
        x2=(2*c-sqrt(discriminant))/(divisor);
    }
    else if (discriminant ==0)
    {
        x1=x2=(2*c)/(divisor);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Invalid Value"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    cout<<"x1= "<< x1 <<endl;
    cout<<"x2= "<< x2 <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I finally got it to compile with no errors by making changes you suggested and altering my else if statement and adding a while. Thanks for your help.